# Phonegapp CSS issue

Tags: ios, css, cordova, uiwebview, phonegap-build

I have some issues with my Phonegap app concerning the UI. When I view it in my Desktop browser it looks like this(the way it shoul be):

[image]

But when I implement it in Phonegap (on iOS) it looks like this:
[image]

This is my html:

```
<div id="page1">
            <div id="formScales">
                <div class="formContent" id="noise">
                    <p>Noise</p>
                    <input type="button" id="nbtn1" value="Noisy" />
                    <input type="button" id="nbtn2" value="Medium noisy" />
                    <input class="active" type="button" id="nbtn3" value="Neutral" />
                </div>
      [...]
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
[...]
#formScales {
    position: relative;
    /* otherwise the float of the child gets it out
         of the document flow */
    overflow:auto;
}

input {
    color: #3B444B;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #606060;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.active {
    background-color: #99CCFF !important;
    border: 1px solid #606060;
}

#noise {
    float: left;
    width: 31vw;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 204, 204, 0.3);
}
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the Objective-C UIWebView class used by iOS... I would be happy about any advice on how to fix this - also what would be best to test the UI without always having to rebuild the PG app!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

adding "webkit-appearance:none" to input did the trick!

```
input {
    /* webkit-appearance:none to override standard button design! */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether your page contents are overlapping on status bar of i-phone? Actually I unable to see it in screenshot. If it is, then you can do this in your config.xml. I was having same issue, I solved it by adding these lines to config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
```

You can test UI on android emulator, without building app on PG-build, but this will not ensure you that you will get correct results for iOS also, I mean if you tested UI on android emulator, then it isn't guaranteed that it will work well on i-phone. So I will recommend you to use PG-build